# How to transfer ERC-721 tokens from multiple wallets to a single wallet?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, nft

Is it possible to transfer ERC-721 tokens from multiple wallets to a single wallet in one transaction? If not, is there another quick way? I'm interested as I mint a lot of tokens (50+) to multiple wallets, and want to merge these all into one wallet quickly. What kind of a smart contract would I need to write for this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to transfer ERC-721 tokens from multiple wallets to a single wallet in one transaction?

No it's not possible. You can always write your own ERC-721 token contract that supports such functionality. Normal NFTs do not desire this functionality as it only makes bot minting easier and bot minters is something the community does not tolerate.

Comment: Confused by your answer, you say it's not possible but that I can write a contract that does this? Which one is it?

Comment: Your question is vague on details so it is hard to give an answer. Please read https://xyproblem.info/ and edit your question and update it with details why you are doing it and more context and maybe I can clarify.